# Import XML file to Excel in three different pieces

Tags: xml, vba, excel

My XML file looks like this:

[image]

When I import this file to Excel, I get a table with its contents. However, I need three separate tables for each of the tags:

```
<Header>
<MasterFiles>
<SourceDocuments>
```

since they look like three related tables.

The code I'm using to import the file is:

```
strTargetFile = "C:\SAFT.xml"
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

But how to break the XML file into three pieces and import each to a different sheet?

Comment: What in the XML is determining a second, and third, piece?

Comment: Brute force: Create 3 copies of the file, and use MSXML2.DOMDocument to open them *as* XML, removing all but the elements you need, then save the XML file, then open the XML files using the `Workbooks.OpenXML` method..

Comment: @BruceWayne the file is broken into <Header>, <MasterFiles> and <SourceDocuments>

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XSLT via VBA's [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to extract the nodes from larger XML into separate XML files and import all three separately into different workbooks:

**XSLT** *(embedded in macro below where select node changes)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">   
      <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>       
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Excel macro**

```
Sub ExtractData()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle

    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim nodeArray As Variant, item As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook

    nodeArray = Array("Header", "MasterFiles", "SourceDocuments")

    ' LOADING ORIGINAL XML FILE '
    xmlDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Audit.xml"

    For Each item In nodeArray

        ' LOADING EMBEDDED STRING XSLT DYNAMICALLY SELECTING NODE '
        xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
                        & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "" _
                        & " xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
                        & "<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
                        & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
                        & "<xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
                        & "<xsl:copy-of select=" & Chr(34) & item & Chr(34) & "/>" _
                        & "</xsl:template>" _
                        & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

        ' TRANSFORMING ORIGINAL XML '
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

        ' OUTPUTTING TRANSFORMED SMALLER XML FILES '
        newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & item & ".xml"

        ' OPENING EACH XML FILE INTO WORKBOOK '
        Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & item & ".xml", LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)

    Next item

    MsgBox "Successfully transformed and loaded XML files!", vbInformation

    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add the reference "Microsoft XML, v.6,0" and run the code, but it isn't working, I guess I need another reference?

Comment: Interesting...try Microsoft XML, v.3.0. Are you using  Windows or Mac?